# Hive JDBC connection breaks

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am using the Hive JDBC driver to automate creating orc tables from textfile tables. For some of the larger tables, I think my connection is timing out and while the map reduce job triggered for the conversion goes through (according to hadoop job tracker), the table never gets created. I have a feeling this is because my Hive connection times out.

How can I fix this?